# Field calculator adding column entries

Tags: qgis

I would like to calculate a summarising column in QGIS. I have a couple of columns lets say `x1, x2, ..x12` with string entries. Now I would like to count the entries over all columns i.e. `x1` is not null then `1`, `x2` is not null then `1+1=2, x3` is not null `1+1+1=3`,  `x4` is null `1+1+1+0=3` etc. For some columns I would like to add more e.g. `x5` is not null then `1+1+1+0+4= 7`.

I tried with case when  `"x1"` is not null then `1` when `"x2"` is not null then `+1` when `"x3"`  is not null then `+4` when...

Is there an easy way to do?

Comment: Not really since you have inconsistent rules about null or not null it makes it difficult using some automation. You might condense the code using Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but kind of tricky :

```
eval(
  array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
      map_akeys(
        attributes()
      ),
      attribute(@element) IS NOT NULL
    ),
    delimiter:='+'
  )
)
```

---

Code explanation (from the middle) :

- `attributes()` : get a dictionary of fields and values
- `map_akeys` : get the keys of the dictionary = Fields
- `attribute(...)` : with a Field name, get the attribute value of the feature
- `array_foreach` : do an expression for each element of the array
- `attribute(@element) IS NOT NULL` : for each Field name, test if it is not null, result is a list of each test
- `array_to_string` : convert the result list into a string separated by delimiter `+`
- `eval` : evaluate a string expression like `'1+1+0+1+1'`

At the `attribute(@element) IS NOT NULL`, you can update this part with a `CASE WHEN @element = 'x4' THEN attribute(@element) IS NULL ELSE attribute(@element) IS NOT NULL END`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement your suggestion or find an other work around